# Calling NativeQuery.executeUpdate outside of transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

We're migrating from Dropwizard 0.9.2 to 1.1.0 which includes migration from Hibernate 4.3.11 to Hibernate 5.2.8.

At the end of the session, we need to issue the SQL command `DISCARD ALL` to our PostgresQL database, which used to work with a simple

```
session.createSqlQuery("DISCARD ALL").executeUpdate();
```

outside of a transaction. PostgresQL forbids running this command in a transaction block.

Hibernate 5 complains with a `TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`.

Can I use Hibernate 5 to issue such a command outside of a transaction or do I need to resort to JDBC by using session.doWork(...)?

We're creating all transactions manually (using session.getTransaction().begin()) with no Transaction Manager in place, if that information is relevant.